# AngularJS multiple validations on single element and validation without required

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a form and using the inbuilt `AngularJS`validations objects to validate the form. I have following form:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="DoSomething()" novalidate>
            <textarea name="EmailTo" required="" rows="2" cols="20" ng-pattern="EmailRegEx" ng-model="EmailTo"></textarea>
            <textarea name="EmailCC" rows="2" cols="20" ng-pattern="EmailRegEx" ng-model="EmailCC"></textarea>
            <textarea name="EmailBCC" required="" rows="2" cols="20" ng-pattern="EmailRegEx" ng-model="EmailBCC"></textarea>
</form>
```

I am displaying the error messages like this:

```
<ul>
      <li ng-if="!myForm.EmailTo.$valid">Please enter email To</li>
      <li ng-if="!myForm.EmailCC.$valid">Please enter email CC</li>
      <li ng-if="!myForm.EmailBCC.$valid">Please enter email BCC</li>
</ul>
```

In the above form , the `EmailTo` and `EmailBCC` are mandatory so I have added the `required` attribute on them and `EmailCC` is not mandatory so there is no `required` attribute on it. I have two questions:

1. Since `EmailCC` is not mandatory, how can I validate it without adding the `required` attribute in case the user enters any value in it?
2. How can I display separate messages for `required` and `ng-pattern` validations? Display a message when the `EmailTo` field is empty and display another message when the entered email is not valid?

**EDIT:**

I have declared message with combination of $valid and $untouched to show message when field is empty and when field is not valid like this:

```
<li ng-if="myForm.EmailTo.$untouched">Please enter email To</li>
<li ng-if="(!myForm.EmailTo.$untouched && myForm.EmailTo.$invalid)">Please enter valid emails seaparated by ';' in email To</li>
```

The above invalid message is displayed only when the control loses focus (`onblur`) and not on `keypress`, I want the valid message to be displayed on `keypress` instead of when control loses focus. Also when I make the control empty, is still displays the invalid message instead of the empty message. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For your first question:

> In AngularJS inputs have the following states:
>
> - $untouched The field has not been touched yet
> - $touched The field has been touched
> - $pristine The field has not been modified yet
> - $dirty The field has been modified
> - $invalid The field content is not valid
> - $valid The field content is valid
>
> Source: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

You can check if EmaillCC input is pristine with something like this in your controller:

```
var isEmailCCPristine = $scope.myForm.EmailCC.$pristine;
```

2) By placing the correct condition in the list items `ng-if`:

```
<li ng-if="myForm.EmailTo.$untouched">Please enter email To</li>
<li ng-if="myForm.EmailTo.$invalid">Please enter a valid email To</li>
```

I didn't test but you might have to adjust this codeblock according to your needs.

Comment: the problem is the `$valid` is always `true` even if I enter incorrect email because I am setting the ng-model property on page load from server so the textarea will have correct data on page load...I have edited my question regarding this...

Comment: Share your `EmailRegEx` - what does it contain?

Comment: Regex: /^((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([;])*)*$/    to check valid multiple emails separated by semi colon `;`

Comment: nvm, I got confused with the RegEx validation, it is working as expected...I have updated the question with another issue when displaying error messages...

Comment: You should open a different question instead, otherwise some user with a similar question will get confused by the amount of answers/comments and editions to the original question since the problems are not related.

Comment: To solve the empty invalid, you can use a combination of `ng-if="myForm.EmailTo.$dirty && myForm.EmailTo.$error.invalid"`

Answer (score 0):

There is already a directive. You can use `ngMessages` for this. Link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

Example:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label>
    Enter your name:
    <input type="text"
           name="myName"
           ng-model="name"
           ng-minlength="5"
           ng-maxlength="20"
           required />
  </label>
  <pre>myForm.myName.$error = {{ myForm.myName.$error | json }}</pre>

  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
  </div>
</form>
```